# Box2d Filtering mask, group category

Tags: java, filter, libgdx, box2d

I have two body def, creating : Body A and Body B, and a JOINT to link them

**I would like that Body A can Collide with Body B only if they are linked**

Meanwhile, a **Body B** can't collide another **Body B**, a **Body A** can't collide another **Body A**.

a **Body B** can't collide a **Body A** that is not linked to him.

**What mask, category and group can I assign** ? I'm lost I don't figure out.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably several ways to accomplish this, but one that comes to mind is:
Set the category and filters such that A and B do not normally collide.

Next, give each pair of objects it own unique group id, with a positive integer.  This will ensure objects within the group collide with each other regardless of the normal rules for A and B, while different groups will use the normal rules (and thus not collide)

Constructor for the group object could take a group id, then

```
public JoinedObjects(int groupId){

    FixtureDef fdefa = new FixtureDef();
    fdefa.filter.categoryBits = 1;//category A
    fdefa.filter.maskBits = 0;//collide with nothing

    FixtureDef fdefb = new FixtureDef();
    fdefb.filter.categoryBits = 2;//category B
    fdefb.filter.maskBits = 0;//collide with nothing

    fdefa.filter.groupIndex = uniqueGroupId;//will collide with the rest of this group
    fdefb.filter.groupIndex = uniqueGroupId;//will collide with the rest of this group

    .....
}
```

Then create each group by

```
JoinedObjects firstGroup = new JoinedObjects(uniqueGroupId);
uniqueGroupId++;
JoinedObjects secondGroup = new JoinedObjects(uniqueGroupId);
uniqueGroupId++;
```